# Como executar um laço enquanto aguarda entrada?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

Quero saber se tem como executar um laço de repetição enquanto aguarda uma entrada do tipo input() e logo após receber a entrada o laço **for** ou **while** começa a processá-la imediatamente.

algo como:

```
imputs = []
parar = false
def faca_algo(i):
    #fazendo algo


inputs.append(input("diga algo: ") # <--- essa linha permaneçe ativa

while not parar: #    <---- esse loop continua sendo executado
    faca_algo(inputs)
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais especifico? Eu ñ entendi o que vc quer. Fornecer [exemplos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ajuda também.

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Se esse "algo" que você quer fazer independe do conteúdo digitado, basta criar uma nova [thread](http://recologia.com.br/2015/07/programacao-multi-thread-em-python/) e executá-la de forma paralela à thread que está fazendo a leitura do terminal. Já tentou algo do tipo? [Este outro artigo](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/20127/py/threads-em-python?trace=1519021197&source=single) também pode ser útil.

Comment: é justamente o contrario, a função recebe os novos parametros e os processa constantemente, nunca parando, enquanto o usuário digita novas entrdas.

Comment: ah, ok. Mas podia ter deixado mais claro na pergunta. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim é possível, mas não com uma única `Thread`, tendo em vista que os programas são sequências de instruções.

Se entendi o que vc deseja, este é um tipo mais simples do problema do `Produtor/Consumidor` (pois não acho que tenha limitação de memória). Vc precisará trabalhar com pelo menos duas `threads` e uma área de memória compartilhada(um `vetor`, ou `lista`, etc.[tratarei aqui como `lista`]) entre as duas threads.

Enquanto a `thread produtora` lê os dados do terminal e os guarda na `lista` a `thread consumidora` retira o próximo elemento da lista e realiza o processamento desejado.

Porém trabalhar com áreas de memórias compartilhadas traz alguns problemas como, no caso de a `thread consumidora` tentar pegar um elemento e a `lista` estiver vazia. Para solucionar este problema vc terá que usar `semáforos`, `locks` e etc.

Para um estudo mais aprofundado sugiro a leitura destes artigos.

Este aqui melhor entendimento do problema do Produtor e Consumidor

> https://ces33.blogspot.com.br/2009/05/o-problema-do-jantar-dos-filosofos-com.html

Este aqui para mecanismos de sincronização de threads em python

> https://tibugs.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/python-compartilhando-recursos-e-sincronizando-threads-parte-1/

Comment: Era isso mesmo! não tenho limitação de memoria, na verdade a ideia é que o consumidor acesse qualquer item sem o remover e se precisar ele pode acessar novamente, nem me veio a cabeça, usar duas threads kk.